# GLSL Shadowmap generating incorrect shadow for some view direction

Tags: opengl, glsl, shadow

I am implementing shadow map in  GLSL shader and got something like the attached image. I am pretty sure as you can see the shadow for the left sphere is not correct. Can anyone point out why this is happening? This kind of shadow appears only for some particular view direction as I move the scene using mouse.

[image: Glsl Shadow map with incorrect shadow]

Comment: What kind of shadow technique are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you aren't rendering whole scene in the shadow map so part of the sphere doesn't fit in. Fixing shadow camera(light source camera) properties should help you.

Comment: The problem is solved, all I had to do was to change my light position and move it further away.. and it works .. thanks for the help..